# c# - how to remove the (32 Bit) - ending in Task-Manager from an app

Tags: c#, taskmanager

I'm writing a console application. I'm wondering that 95 % of names in the *Task Manager* dont have the ending "... (32 Bit)".

Is it possible to remove the "...(32 bit)"-ending in your application name, which is shown in Task-Manager? For this I have created two examples:

Here is a example, how it looks normal

[image]

Here is a example, how I want that it looks like

[image]

Thanks guys for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL DR;** Yes, just compile your app as **64 bit**.

Windows Task Manager on 64 bit OS distinguishes 32 and 64 bit apps by suffixing 32 bit apps with *"(32 bit)"*.